# Trouble with setting for new monitor

Tags: linux-mint, drivers

I have an old machine with AMD 64 and Radeon VTI graphics. When MS quit supporting XP I partitioned the HD and installed LinuxMint 14 (since upgraded). At the time I was using a 17" ViewSonic monitor. I purchased a new 24" Dell monitor and when I boot up XP it appears to work fine (aspect ratio a bit distorted). When I boot LinuxMint, as soon as I enter my password the monitor goes to mush and the machine locks up. I can go back to the ViewSonic but I'm not sure what to download or do the be able to use the Dell. I am also concerned about changing the settings while using the ViewSonic because it may stop working. Any suggestions?

```
$ lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480 [Radeon Xpress 200 Series]
```

Comment: as a first step, you could try to disable any expensive graphics operations. e.g. disable 3d acceleration. As a next step, you could identify your graphics card model: please post the output of `lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D`

Comment: Are you shure the machine locks up? Did you try to ssh to it or so? Does Ctrl+Alt+F1 switch to a text login?

Comment: The lock up happened after I entered my password. Previous to that the screen looked fine. After the lock up I could see a cursor near the bottom but the mouse could not move it. I tried Ctrl_Alt_Delete a couple of times when that did not work I tried to switch the machine off but on response to that either. So I tripped the power strip.

Comment: I disabled 3d acceleration, Changed the resolution and frequency to match what XP thought the new monitor was.

Comment: 1920x1080 and 75Hz. XP had 70 Hz but MInt only shows 60 and 75 Hz. Mint now works on the new monitor but once I open FireFox or Chrom the screen turns white and the machine appears to lock. I tried the Ctrl+Alt+F1 but that only works while Mint is booting.